# The code that works individually breaks in the loop on 3rd-4th iteration, no matter what the input is

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a script (can't publish all of it here, it is big), that downloads the CSV file, checks the rages and creates a new CSV file that has all "out of range" info.

The script was checked on all existing CSV files and works without errors.

Now I am trying to loop through all of them to generate the "out of range" data but it errors after the 3rd or 4th iteration no matter what the input file is.

I tried to swap the queue of files, and the ones that errored before are processed just fine, but the error still appears on 3rd-4th iteration.

What may be the issue with this?

The error I get is the `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

when I run the line assigning the out of range values to the column

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe['Flagged_measure'] == flags[i][0], ['Flagged_measure']] = dataframe[dataframe['Flagged_measure'] == flags[i][0]]['Flagged_measure'].astype(str)  + ' , ' + csv_report_df.loc[flags[i][1], flags[i][0]].astype(str)
```

Comment: Nothing can be known without the code

Comment: Yeah, I thought so.. I hoped maybe someone had similar issue and the issue is related to something else, as the error seems to be pretty random. Something is wrong though

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueError` you mentioned occurs when you join/assign to a column that has duplicate index values. From what I can infer from the single line of code you posted, I'll break it down and maybe it could be clear whether your assignment makes sense:

```py
dataframe.loc[dataframe['Flagged_measure'] == flags[i][0], ['Flagged_measure']]
```

I equate the rows of the column `Flagged_measure` in `dataframe` that matches with `flags[i][0]` with some RHS value, preferably a single value per iteration.

```py
dataframe[dataframe['Flagged_measure'] == flags[i][0]]['Flagged_measure'].astype(str)  + ' , ' + csv_report_df.loc[flags[i][1], flags[i][0]].astype(str)
```

This way of assignment makes no sense whatsoever. You perform a grouped operation but at the same time, use a single-value assignment for changing values in `dataframe`.

Might I suggest you try this?

```py
dataframe['Flagged_measure'] = dataframe['Flagged_measure'].apply(lambda row:  (" , ".join([str(row),str(csv_report_df.iloc[flags[i][1], flags[i][0]]]))) if row == flags[i][0])
```

If it still doesn't work, maybe you need to look into `csv_report_df` as well. As far as I know, `loc` is good for label-based indices, but not for numeric-based indexing, as I think you're looking to achieve here.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining and your time!! There was a little typo? ``` dataframe['Flagged_measure'] = dataframe['Flagged_measure'].apply(lambda row:  (" , ".join([str(row),str(csv_report_df.iloc[flags[i][1],flags[i][0]])])) if row == flags[i][0] )```  I am getting syntax error, will try to expand it and will try again. Thank you

Comment: Sure, just check the brackets, and let me know what kind of error it is. Also it would help if you could just paste like 3 rows of flags dataframe and the csv_report_df as an example, so I know what type of data you're working with.